# is it possible to recreate for loop in c++ with a function

Tags: c++, templates, function, loops

I recently wrote a simple macro because I was so tired of typing the same thing for every vector I needed to loop through:

```
#define FORVEC(a,b) for(int b=0;b<a.size();b++)
```

so I could do something like

```
vector<sometype> stuff

FORVEC(stuff,i)
{
     stuff[i].dosomething();
}
```

I try to avoid using macros since I was told at one point by a more experienced programmer to avoid them whenever possible.  also, I'm just curious about how it would be done with a function (or whatever it would take), because that's an area I'd like to explore.  Not specifically recreating this macro necessarily, though that would be a good start, but something where after defining it, I could do something like

```
mylooperfunction(param1,param2,param3) 
{
     //and now any code here would be run and looped in a way controlled by and defined in mylooperfunction
}
```

Comment: Are you using Boost, i.e., `BOOST_FOREACH`?

Comment: I'm not, but now that the word BOOST seems to come up any time I research things I'd like to be able to do, it's time to start learning.  Also, I suppose part two of my question was unclear.  is it possible to create your own function that would do what std::for_each does, or what BOOST_FOREACH does?

Comment: Is C++0x an option? Range-based for loops are a pretty handy thing.

Comment: Just a note on macros: If you want to change how something syntactically works, you need a macro. `BOOST_FOREACH` is also a macro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a significantly more advanced version in `BOOST_FOREACH` that you can use in C++03. What you're talking about isn't in C++03 but *is* in C++0x with the introduction of lambda expressions.

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](const T& ref) {
    ref.do_something();
});
```

Specifically for this use, there's even a new language feature for it, which in my opinion is a horrific mistake, but that's just me. The above code is much more general-case.

Comment: Even better is a range-based for loop.

Comment: @GMan: @DeadMG seems to utterly dislike, if not hate the range-based `for`. :) That's what his last paragraph is talking about.

Comment: @Xeo: Oh, that does make more sense now, and I do recall knowing about that ill-formed opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The STL Algorithms provide the function you are looking for: [std::for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/)

Comment: wow...thats useful to know...thanks, but as I said...still curious to know if it's possible to write your own function that does this, and how

Comment: You can write a template function by yourself, if you follow my link, you can see how it could look like.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions that already do that: `BOOST_FOREACH` and `std::for_each`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what will happen:

1. you forget the name of your macro
2. you start typing existing iterator stuff over and over again
3. soon typing it is so automatic that it'll be easy and fast to do
4. then your macro will no longer be needed

Of course, getting there takes small amount of effort, but everyone will get there at some point...